# Cannot Generate SVG using MathJax-node on sample

Tags: svg, mathjax

MathJax and Node newbie is getting `undefined` output when trying to generate svg using the slightly modified sample from here https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node

```
// a simple TeX-input example
var mjAPI = require("mathjax-node");
mjAPI.config({
  MathJax: {
    // traditional MathJax configuration
  }
});
mjAPI.start();

var yourMath = 'E = mc^2';

mjAPI.typeset({
  math: yourMath,
  format: "TeX", // or "inline-TeX", "MathML"
  svg:true,      // was mml:true
}, function (data) {
  if (!data.errors) {console.log(data.mml)}
});
```

Sample run:-

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\math-eqn>node math-eqn.js
undefined
```

The original sample works fine:-

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\math-eqn>node math-eqn.js
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block" alttext="E = mc
^2">
  <mi>E</mi>
  <mo>=</mo>
  <mi>m</mi>
  <msup>
    <mi>c</mi>
    <mn>2</mn>
  </msup>
</math>
```

Comment: Try changing `data.mml` to `data.svg`.

Comment: So sorry, I missed that. Would you like to make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `data.mml` to `data.svg` in the `console.log()` since you disabled MathML generation.